# How do I get all the text under a tag with Nokogiri?

Tags: html, ruby, xpath, nokogiri

In this example I am trying to get the text from within the `<td>` tag of a table.  First, the html code.

```
<table>
  <tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>Single line of text</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Text here<p>First line</p><p>Second line</p></td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Then the ruby code here.

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'pp'

html = File.open('test.html').read
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(html)
rows = doc.xpath('//table[1]/tbody/tr')

data = rows.collect do |row|
  row.at_xpath('td[1]/text()').to_s
end

pp data
```

And the result that I get is.

```
["Single line of text", "Text here"]
```

How can I get all of the text in the second `<td>` tag?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two changes you will need to make to get all the `text` nodes. First `at_xpath` will only ever return a single node, so to get multiple nodes you’ll need to use `xpath`.

Second, to get all descendant nodes, not just child nodes, use `//` instead of `/`.

Combining these, the line of code would be:

```
row.xpath('td[1]//text()').to_s
```

This will concatenate all the text nodes together, giving the result:

```
["Single line of text", "Text hereFirst lineSecond line"]
```

which may not be what you want. Rather than just call `to_s` on the resulting nodeset you will need to process to fit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
pp doc.search("//tr[2]//td//text()").map { |item| item.text }
```

As matt says, you can get all descendants using `//`.

You can also index the second `tr` if you want that one specifically. Just leave out the indexing to get all the `tr`s.

And you can filter the resulting text objects to get only those that have a `td` upstream.

Finally, map over each Nokogiri object, plucking out the text into the final array, which looks like this:

```
["Text here", "First line", "Second line"]
```

Answer (score 0):

You want the `text` method of `Nokogiri::XML::Node` if you want to get all the text for any element:

```
p doc.xpath('//table[1]/tbody/tr').map{ |tr| tr.text.strip }
#=> ["Single line of text", "Text hereFirst lineSecond line"]
```

(The `strip` method just gets rid of leading and trailing whitespace.)